# CakePHP y SqlServer consulta

Tags: php, cakephp, model

necesito hacer una consulta a una base de datos con SQLServer y comprar 2 fechas el problema es que CakePHP le pone '' a la fecha y me lanza error tabla.campo >= '2017-03-25' y necesito que quede como esto tabla.campo >= 2017-03-25

Comment: Amigo te recomiendo que leas datepicker que te ayuda :

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: gracias pero los datos los obtengo en el mismo servidor no desde la vista